# What do bunny carrots do?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

In The Simpsons Tapped Out, what do the carrots do for the player on Cletus's farm? It takes 4 hours to harvest, and I don't see any more bunnies coming from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you harvest a carrots crop (4 hours) you gain 10 rabbits. Make sure you clear your town of rabbits before you harvest, there is a rabbit limit.

Comment: BONUS: if you harvest carrots the bunnies sometimes drop golden eggs 